# Shutdown freeze after system updates

Tags: freeze, swap, reboot

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and this morning the computer requested to restart after system updates I restart but it froze on the shut down at the Deactivating swap step. Should I turn off the PC from the CPU considering this was right after actualizations? I have read other post about fixing the bug but I don't know if I should kill the PC from the power button.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you certain you are on 20.04? Until now my impression was that this bug impacted only 22.04... Could you please confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a lot of people are having similar issues today on Ubuntu 22.04.3.
In my case, I restarted the computer, but after that my x was broken.

I fixed the issue by installing ubuntu-desktop:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

I also had issues with some of the drivers, so I reinstalled them with:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

Looks like the issue is caused by:
[Bug #2030262 System broken after upgrade](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/2030262)